# Hash table addFunction

Tags: c++, hashtable, addition

I'm trying to make a simple hash table project. I was testing my program when I noticed the addPlayer function isn't working. addPlayer relies on a few other functions but I checked those functions as well and can't find the error. Any help on this would be really appreciated, if I could diagnose this myself I would.
The program in its entirety is below:

Header File (Player.h)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

    using namespace std;

    #ifndef PLAYER_H
    #define PLAYER_H

    class Player
    {
    private:
        static const int tableSize = 10;

        struct player
        {
            string name;
            string race;
            player* next;
        };

        player* HashTable[tableSize];

    public:
        //Constructor
        Player();
        //Hash function
        int hash(string key);
        //Adds players and takes in their attributes
        void addPlayer(string name, string race);
        //Counts number of players in index
        int numPlayersInIndex(int index);
        //Prints information from the items held in the hash table
        void printTable();
    };
    #endif
```

Main (Main.cpp)

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

//Custom headers
#include "Player.h"
//Pause console before exiting window
#include <stdlib.h>

#ifdef _WIN32
#define WINPAUSE system("pause")
#endif

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    //Test addPlayer
    Player player1;
    player1.addPlayer("happy", "elf");
    player1.addPlayer("happy", "elf");
    player1.addPlayer("happy", "elf");
    player1.addPlayer("happy", "elf");
    player1.addPlayer("happy", "elf");
    player1.addPlayer("hapdsfdsfsdsdfsdfsdfpy", "elf");
    player1.addPlayer("happy", "elf");
    player1.addPlayer("happy", "elf");
    player1.addPlayer("happy", "elf");
    player1.addPlayer("happy", "elf");
    player1.printTable();

    //Call WINPAUSE to pause console window before exiting
    WINPAUSE;
    return 0;
}
```

Class (Player.cpp)

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include "Player.h"

using namespace std;


//Player constructor sets default values for the attributes
//of the player
Player::Player()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < tableSize; i++)
    {
        HashTable[i] = new player;
        HashTable[i]->name = "empty";
        HashTable[i]->race = "empty";
        HashTable[i]->next = NULL;
    }
}

void Player::addPlayer(string name, string race)
{
    int index = hash(name);
    //Check to see if the attributes have been set at index
    if (HashTable[index]->name == "empty")
    {
        HashTable[index]->name == name;
        HashTable[index]->race == race;
    }

    //If they've already been set, then make an addition to the list
    else
    {
        player* ptr = HashTable[index];
        player* newPlayer = new player;
        newPlayer->name = name;
        newPlayer->race = race;
        newPlayer->next = NULL;
        //Traverse to the end of the list
        while (ptr->next != NULL)
        {
            ptr = ptr->next;
        }
        //Links the last item in the list to the new player being added
        //New player now sits at the end of the list
        ptr->next = newPlayer;
    }
}

//Function to count the number of players
int Player::numPlayersInIndex(int index)
{
    //Sentinal variable to keep track of positon in list
    int count = 0;

    //If the index is empty, or has default value, return 0 to mark
    //as empty. 
    if (HashTable[index]->name == "empty")
    {
        return count;
    }

    //Otherwise, increment count and then traverse the list pointed to
    //in the hash table.
    else
    {
        count++;
        player* ptr = HashTable[index];
        while (ptr->next != NULL)
        {
            count++;
            ptr = ptr->next;
        }
    }
    return count;
}

void Player::printTable()
{
    //Holds number of elements in each bucket
    int number;
    for (int i = 0; i < tableSize; i++)
    {
        //Sets number to the number of players in the hash table
        number = numPlayersInIndex(i);
        cout << "-------------" << endl;
        cout << "index = " << i << endl;
        cout << HashTable[i]->name << endl;
        cout << HashTable[i]->race << endl;
        cout << "Number of characters: " << number << endl;
        cout << "-------------" << endl;
    }
}

//Recursive function to create simple and fairly unique hash pattern
//to process objects
int Player::hash(string key)
{
    int hash = 0;
    int index;

    for (int i = 0; i < key.length(); i++)
    {
        hash = hash + (int)key[i];
    }

    index = hash % tableSize;

    return index;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    HashTable[index]->name == name;
    HashTable[index]->race == race;
```

change it to

```
    HashTable[index]->name = name;
    HashTable[index]->race = race;
```

Comment: Ah, thank you so much! I just tested and it's only adding the 6th element though. Any thoughts?

Comment: it's not the 6th element but the 6th index.

Comment: your hash table has 10 slots, if two keys hash to the same slot (example : 6%10 = 6, 16%10 = 6), you'll use a linked list to store them.

Comment: Okay so I just need some sort of conflict resolution? That's called chaining, right? Thank you again.

Comment: it's already taken care of inside addPlayer function, your printTable function though is only printing the head of each index, use `player *head = HashTable[i]; while (head) { cout << head->name; ... head = head->next; }`